# Jenkins build pipeline resets objectstoreV2 value on Cloudhub

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, maven-3, mulesoft

I have a build pipeline building a Mulesoft API and deploying it to cloudhub. The API is using ObjectStore 2 and running on 4.4.0 version.

I am noticing that each time I deploy through Jenkins pipeline, the objectstore flag is getting reset and it is reproducible each time.

We are on Jenkins v2.220 (a bit old for sure),  Maven 3.4, ObjectStore Mule plug in v 1.2.1.

It is really annoyinig as we see the log in Cloudhub  mentioning that CI server has modified the objectstore  property but can't see anything being set through commands visible on pipeline configuration. Mulesoft support  team can also only see what  I see in the audit logs.

Has anyone faced similar situation and is aware of the root cause? Any pointers would also be helpful.

Comment: Please provide details to understand/reproduce the issue. How the pipeline deploys to CloudHub, what commands, Maven configurations, REST APIs of Anypoint Platform it is using, the exact messages in the logs, Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for details on how to ask a question.

Comment: I guess that the Mule Maven Plugin configuration in the pom and the message seem to be most significant pieces of information. The version of Jenkins should be irrelevant. The version of the Mule Maven Plugin is really old. And what is the default in runtime manager?

Comment: I don't have to do anything specific to reproduce it, simply releasing it clears objectstore v2 checkbox. Maven is sending a put request to URL - https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/cloudhub/api/v2/applications/<api-name> to release the API. There is no error as such, all I see is objectstore v2 gets unchecked as soon as the jar file is replaced. POM contains Maven version as 3.6.3. I can reproduce this with other APIs published from Jenkins but nothing visible on the build pipeline command setting it up.

Comment: Please share the configuration as requested

Comment: Below is the command we are using to deploy -                                                       
 clean package deploy -DskipMunitTests -P <env> 
-DmuleDeploy
-Dch.runtime=${ch.runtime}
-DappName=${appName}
-Danypoint.env=${anypoint.env}
-Dch.workers=${ch.workers}
-Dch.workerType=${ch.workerType}
-Drevision=${appVersion}-%GIT_COMMIT:~0,8%
-DappVersion=${appVersion}-%GIT_COMMIT:~0,8%
-Danypoint.region=${ANYPOINT_REGION}
-Danypoint.user=${ANYPOINT_USER}
-Danypoint.password=${ANYPOINT_PASSWORD}
-Danypoint.url=${ANYPOINT_URI}

Comment: Maven version is  3.4 as mentioned earlier. REST put request is being made to the URL - anypoint.mulesoft.com/cloudhub/api/v2/applications/<api-name> to deploy the jar on cloudhub. There is no error in log on Jenkins or Cloudhub. The only observation is ObjectStore V2 is getting ticked off and we can see in Cloudhub Audit logs that it is being done by Jenkins server but nothing explicitly being done as you can see in the Maven command above. This can be reproduced as many times as we want, not sure if there is a reported bug or a known issue with Maven / REST API of Anypoint Platform.

Comment: Please also share the Mule Maven Plugin configuration from the pom.

Comment: Hi  Aled, below are the Maven  plug in details from  pom.   Just one more finding we have, deploying  from command line does not cause the issue.                                  
                         <plugin>
    <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.5</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
     <classifier>mule-application</classifier>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>

Comment: What is the command line when it works and what is the command line from Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

Mule Maven Plugin 3.3.5 is very old at this time. Many new releases have been made since its release that fix several bugs, including one related to the default Objectstore v2 configuration. Also security vulnerabilities fixes. Try with to update to the **latest available version** of the Mule Maven Plugin. You can find the information about the latest release and all release notes at https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/mule-maven-plugin/mule-maven-plugin-release-notes